# Setup application.js or ga.js or beginner's guide to google analytics?

Tags: javascript, php, html, yii, google-analytics

Sorry for asking this here, is there a link to a full guide or guide here in setting up with examples google analytics? All i could see was setting up the signing up and getiing a tracking code. Then it ends there. I also have other questions.

1. When putting up the code before header, i read that when page is loaded, the code is run. So does going to different pages of the same site be counted as different views? e.g going to mysite.com, then mysite.com/info, then mysite.com/contacts. Does this send/create 3 different page views? How can i make it to only one? If it is the same user and just going through different sections?
2. Can i ask for sample on how to get those views? When i visited the api site, i could only see the metrics. There was no sample format and im a complete noob. Scenario, i have a site `monitoringSite.com` and from there i want to request the page views of `mysite.com`. I really just want the unique user page views. I really would appreciate there was a sample of a request or request code like,

   ```
     $this->curl('https://googleanalytics.com/idontknowwhattoputhere');
   ```

   And for every request, does it need a login data?

I actually have already created an account and got the UA-XXXXX-X code stuff and i dont know what next to do. I have not put the ga.js thing on `mysite.com`, but after i put it, will it automatically start sending and could get the view through request (If i already know how to request, that is.).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To your point 1: Yes google tracks every page view as a page view (intentional behavior? ;) ). But it also has the capability to show you **Unique Visitors** for example (or **New Visitors**), that should be what you want.

To point 2: First I want to make sure, that you know, there is an [interface from google](http://www.google.com/analytics/) where you can view your data, no need for any API.
Then I want to make sure, you know that there are [client libraries](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api) for [Java](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/), [Python](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/), [PHP](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) and [JavaScript](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/), that make it unnecessary to know the exact URL. Then after you verify, you don't want the libraries or the interface, I will edit the post.

EDIT:
Okay so there is also a category for what you want: **Visits** (it is different than *pageviews*), you can see, how they are calculated [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2731565?hl=en); basically a new visit is after 30 minutes of inactivity or certain other reasonable conditions.

About the plain API thing; this site should be what you are looking for: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference

All infos I can give you are written there.

EDIT 2:
So finally here is a working example (with the placeholding constants replaced, of course):

```
<?php

class GoogleAnalytics {

    // Replace those
    const MAIL = '1234567890@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
    const PRIVATE_KEY_PATH = '/home/matmarbon/path/to/your/'.
            '1234567890abcdef1234567890abcdef12345678-privatekey.p12';
    const VIEW_ID = 12345678;
    const CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER = false;// ATTENTION: THIS MIGHT BE DANGEROUS!

    // Don't replace those
    const AUTHURL = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';
    const SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly';

    public function curl($url, $post, $params) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        if($post) {
            $query = '';
            foreach($params as $k => $v)
                $query .= $k.'='.urlencode($v).'&';
            rtrim($query, '&');
            curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
                CURLOPT_POST => count($params),
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $query
            ));
        } else if($params) {
            $url .= '?';
            foreach($params as $k => $v)
                $url .= $k.'='.urlencode($v).'&';
            rtrim($url, '&');
        }
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => self::CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER
        ));
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        if($output === false)
            throw new Exception('Error getting auth code: '.curl_error($ch));
        curl_close($ch);
        return $output;
    }

    public function auth($mail,$privateKeyPath,$force=false) {
        if(!$force && !empty($_SESSION['ga_auth']))
            if($_SESSION['ga_auth_time'] > time())
                return $_SESSION['ga_auth'];
        $jwt = 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.';
        $claimset = array(
            'iss' => $mail,
            'scope' => self::SCOPE,
            'aud' => self::AUTHURL,
            'exp' => time() + 60 * 60,
            'iat' => time()
        );
        // utf8_encode ?
        $jwt .= base64_encode(json_encode($claimset));

        $c = array();
        $key = file_get_contents($privateKeyPath);
        openssl_pkcs12_read($key, $c, 'notasecret');
        $pkeyid = openssl_get_privatekey($c['pkey']);
        $sgn = '';
        openssl_sign($jwt, $sgn, $pkeyid, "sha256");
        openssl_free_key($pkeyid);
        $jwt .= '.'.base64_encode($sgn);
        $result = json_decode($this->curl(self::AUTHURL,true,array(
            'grant_type' => 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
            'assertion' => $jwt
        )), true);
        $_SESSION['ga_auth'] = $result['access_token'];
        $_SESSION['ga_auth_time'] = time() + $result['expires_in'];
        return $result['access_token'];
    }

    public function getVisitors() {
        $mail = self::MAIL;
        $privateKeyPath = self::PRIVATE_KEY_PATH;
        $auth = $this->auth($mail,$privateKeyPath);

        /// HAVE FUN HERE
        // Example:
        $json = $this->curl('https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga',
                false,
                array(
                    'access_token' => $auth,
                    'ids' => 'ga:'.self::VIEW_ID,
                    'start-date' => '7daysAgo',
                    'end-date' => '1daysAgo',
                    'metrics' => 'ga:visits'
                ));

        return json_decode($json)->totalsForAllResults->{'ga:visits'};
    }

}
session_start();
$ga = new GoogleAnalytics();
echo $ga->getVisitors();
```

The `MAIL` must be one from the developers console, also the private key must be generated there and downloaded - put its file path into the `PRIVATE_KEY_PATH`.
The `VIEW_ID` is *not* your `UA-XXXXX-X` code but can be found in the analytics interface (<kbd>Admin</kbd><kbd>View settings</kbd><kbd>View ID</kbd>) and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` *shoud* be `true`... just try it with `true` and if it doesn't work.. you know... use google and set it to `true` in any live version anyway, because it is vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, Yes new visitors is what i want. :) . Regarding getting data, i actually want to display the data i want in my monitoring site. So i wanted the data in json, and would like to filter the data to only new visitors, and maybe further filter that data to specific date ranges. Libraries are fine but i only want a few data,   no need for a lot of stuff that is why i was wanting to know the just the url to send my request and any other info needed to successfully get the data.

Comment: Also, the ga.js have already been setup on the site. I have the UA-XXXXX-X code, and a Google account.. Thing is i don't know how to request the data. On 'New Visitors' that you mentioned, do they base it on the IP address? How long is a user a new visitor? If the same user visits the next day on the site, will he be a 'New Visitor'? I actually want him to be a new visitor.

Comment: @MikaSa Added the promised edit, hope that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Great link. So i'll just up your answer. But still cant figure out how could get the data properly :( . My question in short, what is the simplest way to getting unique pageviews of a site on google analytics? I already got the client id, created an account, but i cant access or get oauth tokens through php curl. All i need was the proper curl :( . The doc is okay but the steps on setting it up is not. All i wanted was some single data .. :( sorry noob here.

Comment: @MikaSa Okay.. just wait a moment, I will figure it out. (Would also be a nice feature for my own site ;) )

Comment: @MikaSa Hard piece of work, in particular the authentication stuff. But there it is: A working example.

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much.. It worked. Had trouble at first because i did not have the private key. Sorry to bother you many times, where did you get the first part of the string in variable $jwt?

Comment: @MikaSa No problem, I can use it myself. All infos I needed for the authorization part came from Googles document about [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) - also the first part of $jwt. I found that site through the link i already posted via: The "Authorization Guide"-link there and after reading it at the "Service Accounts"-link.